# Identity Server use case for Resource Owner Grant flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3, identityserver4

This question is more like an architecture problem. I wonder if the following setup makes sense.

1. Client: user browser
2. Web server: A server that serve web api for web application.
3. Identity Server

When Client sends a request for login to Web server, Web server receives the request and sends it to Identity server through Resource Owner Grant type to get an access token.

When Client sends a request for resource, it uses the access token from previous step to access the web server, and the web server needs to verify the request with Identity server every time before providing resource.

However, I think this architecture might have some issues like

The web server can't be sure if Client is a trust client even under SSL connection. Client can always get the access token and send request to web server. However, I feel like this problem exist in other grant type as well.
I think as long as the user can't change the grant scope or someone else intercept the token (under SSL connection), it should be fine.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Browser based applications should use an interactive flow - e.g. hybrid flow.

This way the client has to authenticate with idsrv before it can get the token.

Check the OIDC spec:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowAuth

Comment: Well, my question is more like when the web server and IDSrv are both from the same party, what is the benefit to do 3-legged authentication instead of 2-legged ?

Comment: You won't get SSO between multiple apps without the browser flow.

Comment: Good point. So if I make it like Users send username/password to Web srv and Web srv sends it to IDSrv to get Access Token (Resource Owner flow). Once Web srv gets it, sends it back to User. It will still have SSO and User doesn't talk to IDSrv directly with Resource owner flow. Does it work ? Because the other flows need URI redirect which is not really ideal to work with existing native apps.

Comment: @maxisam, did you get it to work that way? I am thinking on doing it like you described. Thanks.

Comment: well, I think it should work, however, this project is currently on hold. It was my testing project on the side. I will get back to it when I can.